# Wiener process restricting increments

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm referencing from Leimkuhler and Matthews' *Molecular Dynamics* textbook.

From my understanding, a Wiener process $W(t)$ is essentially a random walk process at the diffusion limit $\delta x^2\approx\delta t$ and time limit $\delta t\to0$. We can solve for a Wiener process from $0$ to $t$ with the algorithm $W_{n+1} = W_n + \delta x$, where $\delta x$ is a vector satisfying $\vert\!\vert\delta x\vert\!\vert = \sqrt{\delta t}$ and so $\vert\!\vert dW\vert\!\vert$ is fixed as well. Another way to phrase this is
$$\delta x = \hat{R} = \dfrac{R}{\vert\!\vert R\vert\!\vert},$$
where $R$ is a vector sampled iid from a normal distribution.

However, most numerical methods beyond chapter 6 imply that $dW = \sqrt{\delta t}R$. This implies that $\vert\!\vert dW\vert\!\vert$ can take on any nonnegative value.

So how did we transition from
$$W_{n+1} = W_n + \sqrt{\delta t}\hat{R}$$
to
$$W_{n+1} = W_n + \sqrt{\delta t}R?$$

I must have missed something.